# Spring Boot MVC - Custom Converter Number to Enum not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, converters

I tried converting a `Number` to an `Enum` Type with a custom implementation of a `Converter<Number, MyEnum>` in a Spring Boot MVC application. Unfortunately the converter isn't called. Instead spring converts the number as the ordinal number of the enum.
The converter is registered by a `@Component` annotation.

Is there a way to override the default converter for `Number` and `Enum`?

Comment: You want to convert from what to what? Also take into consideration that there is no `Number` in MVC only `String` parameters which can be converted.

Comment: instead of converter, you can add this piece of code to your MyEnum class.   `static MyEnum fromId(int id) {for (MyEnum type : values()) {if (type.getId() == id) { return type; } }return null; }`

Comment: @M.Deinum But what about an object that has a number attribute? Is this also treated as a String by MVC?

Comment: That is a `String` to `Number` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

you can reference to the built-in `StringToEnumConverterFactory` and write a custom converter factory, then register it.

The key is `String` of `StringToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<String, YourEnum>`, instead of `ConverterFactory<Integer, YourEnum>`.

I used `Integer` before, but my custom converter is ignored.